# How to scrape elements that immediately follows a certain element?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have an Html document that look like this:

```
<div id="whatever">
  <a href="unwanted link"></a>
  <a href="unwanted link"></a>
  ...
  <code>blah blah</code>
  ...
  <a href="interesting link"></a>
  <a href="interesting link"></a>
  ...
</div>
```

I want to scrape only links that immediately follows the `code` tag. If I do `soup.findAll('a')` it returns all hyperlinks.

How can I make BS4 to start scraping after that specific `code` element?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try `soup.find_all_next()`:

```
>>> tag = soup.find('div', {'id': "whatever"})
>>> tag.find('code').find_all_next('a')
[<a href="interesting link"></a>, <a href="interesting link"></a>]
>>>
```

It like `soup.find_all()`, but it finds all tags **after a tag**.

---

If you'd like remove the `<a>` tags before `<code>`, we have a function called `soup.find_all_previous()`:

```
>>> tag.find('code').find_all_previous('a')
[<a href="unwanted link"></a>, <a href="unwanted link"></a>]

>>> for i in tag.find('code').find_all_previous('a'):
...     i.extract()
...     
... 
<a href="unwanted link"></a>
<a href="unwanted link"></a>

>>> tag
<div id="whatever">


  ...
  <code>blah blah</code>
  ...
  <a href="interesting link"></a>
<a href="interesting link"></a>
  ...
</div>
>>>
```

So that is:

1. Find all `<a>` tags which before `<code>` tag.
2. Use `soup.extract()` with a `for` loop remove them.

Comment: Thanks, I was unaware of this function. I wonder, is there an easy way to `extract()` or remove the elements that appear before the `code` element from the DOM?

Comment: Excellent! There are other elements that I need to eliminate, but your code gives a good headstart!

Comment: @masroore: Well, remember that there's also `soup.findPrevious()` and `soup.findNext()` if you need just find one element instead of all of that tag. Check [the document](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) for more details.

Answer (score 2):

The easier and simpler way to do this is by passing a string of css selector into the [`.select()`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) method and remove the link using [`decompose`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#decompose). Here you need to use the so called *General Sibling Selector* `~` to select *all* anchors that are siblings of `code`: `code ~ a`

```
soup = BeautifulSoup('''<div id="whatever">
      <a href="unwanted link"></a>
      <a href="unwanted link"></a>
      ...
      <code>blah blah</code>
      ...
      <a href="interesting link"></a>
      <a href="interesting link"></a>
      ...
      </div>''', 
     'lxml'
)

for link in soup.select('code ~ a'):
    link.decompose()     

print(soup)
```

which yields:

```
<html><body><div id="whatever">
<a href="unwanted link"></a>
<a href="unwanted link"></a>
  ...
  <code>blah blah</code>
  ...


  ...
</div></body></html>
```

---

Another way to remove all the link after the `code` tag is to iterate the list returns by the [`find_all`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-all) method to find all the "code" tag in the document and for each tag use the [`find_all_next`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-all-next-and-find-next) which gives you the list of all next `a` tag. You then iterate the list and use [`decompose`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#decompose) to remove the tag from the tree, then completely destroys it and its contents.

Demo

```
In [85]: from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

In [86]: soup = BeautifulSoup('''<div id="whatever">
   ....:   <a href="unwanted link"></a>
   ....:   <a href="unwanted link"></a>
   ....:   ...
   ....:   <code>blah blah</code>
   ....:   ...
   ....:   <a href="interesting link"></a>
   ....:   <a href="interesting link"></a>
   ....:   ...
   ....: </div>''', 'lxml')

In [87]: for code in soup.find_all('code'):
   ....:     for link in code.find_all_next('a'):
   ....:         link.decompose()
   ....:         

In [88]: soup
Out[88]: 
<html><body><div id="whatever">
<a href="unwanted link"></a>
<a href="unwanted link"></a>
  ...
  <code>blah blah</code>
  ...


  ...
</div></body></html>
```